# Verify the Convergence of a Series

Tags: real-analysis

I am having trouble following how the author of my book chose his $N$ when developing the proof of convergence of a series. In the book he outlines a series of steps:

1. Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be arbitrary
2. Demonstrate a choice for $N \in \mathbb{N}$
3. Show $N$ actually works
4. Assume $n \ge N$
5. With a well chosen $N$ we should be able to demonstrate $|x_n - x| \lt \epsilon$.

So I set out to prove it following his example. The problem is as follows:

$lim{\frac{1}{6n^2 +1}} = 0$

So first, $|\frac{1}{6n^2 +1} - 0|$ will always be positive, so we can just work with:

$\frac{1}{6n^2 +1}$.

For  $|x_n - x| \lt \epsilon$ to hold, then

$\frac{1}{6n^2 +1} \lt \epsilon$

Which implies:

$6n^2 + 1 \gt \frac{1}{\epsilon} \implies n^2 >\frac{\frac{1}{\epsilon} - 1}{6}$

$\implies n \gt \sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{\epsilon} - 1}{6}} $

So now we know how $n$ needs to be behave to make sure we are inside of the epsilon neighborhood. If this $n$ works, we should be able to "derive back" the original inequality in the proof. Proof:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Choose some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying n $N \gt \sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{\epsilon} - 1}{6}}$.

Then, to verify our choice of $N$ has the property we desire, let $n \ge N$.

$n \gt \sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{\epsilon} - 1}{6}}$

After some algebra, we arrive at

$\frac{1}{6n^2 +1} - 0 \lt \epsilon$

And so it is shown that for our sequence, $|a_n - 0| \lt \epsilon$.

---

The author however chose a different N. Following the same general layout the author says

let $N \gt \sqrt{1/6 \epsilon}$

It follows that for $n \ge N$

$\frac{1}{6n^2 +1} \lt \epsilon$.

This is remarkably simpler. How did the author arrive at his choice? Did he just keep the dominant terms?

Comment: The author used $\frac{1}{\epsilon} -1 < \frac{1}{\epsilon} $ in the numerator.

Comment: Oh I see, is my overall approach correct then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the author did:

$\frac{1}{6n^2 +1} < \frac{1}{6n^2}$.

$\frac{1}{6n^2} < \epsilon \iff n \gt \sqrt{1/6 \epsilon}.$

If $n \ge \sqrt{1/6 \epsilon}$, then it follows that $|x_n-0|< \epsilon.$

Comment: Interesting, I see. Would this mean that my approach is more susceptible to algebra manipulation error but also correct?

Comment: In $\sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{\epsilon} - 1}{6}}$ we must have that $\frac{1}{\epsilon} - 1>0$. This is the case if $ \epsilon <1.$ Thus your approach is correct, if $ \epsilon <1.$